# Incorrectly infering type for arrays, working for unions

Tags: typescript, type-inference, conditional-types

I would expect Typescript to be able to correctly infer the types in the following code:

```js
type Result = ['A', 'B'] extends [...infer A, ...infer B] ? [A, B] : never;
```

However, both types are infered to be `unknown[]`. **Why is that?** Is there a way to fix this code?

The following code for example does not give `unknown`'s:

```js
type Result = 'A' | 'B' extends infer A | infer B ? A | B : never;
```

Comment: Inferred tuples can be empty (`[]`). So back to your code; is `A` supposed to be `[]`, `["A"]`, or `["A", "B"]`? What about `B`? TypeScript can't choose, so it's `unknown[]`.

Comment: ① This doesn't seem to be a minimal minimal reproducible example; you could pare this down to just `type Result = ['A', 'B'] extends [...infer A, ...infer B] ? [A, B] : never;` as [shown here](//tsplay.dev/N9Oa3W), and have the same issue, without the distractions of object types and multiple inference sites for the same parameter. Would you [edit] to make it more minimal?

Comment: ② And I think the closest we'll get to a canonical answer is in [this ms/TS#39253 comment](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39253#issuecomment-650329102). TS won't make "speculative" inferences to multiple variadic tuple types. Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz thank you, yes that is actually a good reference.

Comment: Okay I’ll write up an answer when I get a chance (on mobile now, might be a few hours)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [conditional type inferrence](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to parse a tuple with consecutive [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) like `[...infer A, ...infer B]` is ambiguous; there's no single "correct" place to split the tuple.  If you're inferring `[...infer A, ...infer B]` from `[X, Y]` then `A` could be `[X]` and `B` could be `[Y]`, but it's equally plausible that `A` could be `[]` and `B` could be `[X, Y]`, or that `A` could be `[X, Y]`, and `B` could be `B`.  In the face of such ambiguity, what should the compiler do?  Well, what it actually does is *just fail to infer at all*.  This is described in [a comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39253#issuecomment-650329102) in [microsoft/TypeScript#39253](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39253) by the lead TypeScript architect and implementer of the variadic tuple types feature in [microsoft/TypeScript#39094](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094):

> The general guiding principle I've used in variadic tuple type inference is to not make speculative inferences. For example, don't attempt to infer to `[...T, number, ...U]` because ... it would often be speculative (e.g. when inferring from `[number, number, number, number]`). A key characteristic of speculative situations is that there is more than one variable length element in the inference target and thus it isn't clear how to group the source elements.

So it gives up and the inferred types fall back to their constraints, which for variadic tuples is `unknown[]`.

---

Contrast this to how [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html), as implemented by the same architect in [microsoft/TypeScript#40336](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336), behave.  One could make the same argument that inferring `` `${infer A}${infer B}` `` from `"XY"` should fail because it's ambiguous; maybe `A` is `"X"` and `B` is `"Y"`, but it's equally plausible that `A` could be `""` and `B` could be `"XY"`, or that `A` could be `"XY"` and `B` could be `""`.

But no, there is an explicit rule that in such cases where placeholders are next to each other, exactly one character is parsed into the first one: "A placeholder immediately followed by another placeholder is matched by inferring a single character from the source."  So what you actually get is `"X"` for `A` and `"Y"` for `B`.

Why? Because you need something like this to split a string into single characters.  It wasn't originally implemented this way but, [according to this commment in microsoft/TypeScript#40336](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336#issuecomment-686232585), "this can be used to perform single character decomposition of strings, e.g. turning a string into a tuple of single characters using a recursive conditional type. I'm still not 100% happy with the fact there is no obvious indication a single character inference is desired, but it seems better than not having the ability at all."

There's no similar deficiency with variadic tuples (you can just use `[infer A, ...infer B]` to perform single element decomposition of tuples), so the "just give up" approach is preferred for consistency's sake.